# Consuming .asmx Web Service in java?

Tags: java, asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a web service that was built in .NET, and published in the IIS 7.5.
I tried it and if it works, but now the issue is how to consume webservice **.asmx**

The problem is that it has the following address, and does not end with wsdl.

***192.168.1.15/webservice/WebServiceFOX.asmx?op=ExisteExpediente***

**Image 01:**  ***http://postimg.org/image/l46c5nt79/***

**Image 02:**  ***http://postimg.org/image/6wgnh0gid/***

The issue is how is a web service without **wsdl** extension, I would not recognize netbeans tool to generate code java me, for later consumption of web service from java.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: both images are dead links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WSDL for the service should be at this URL: `<the_host>/webservice/WebServiceFOX.asmx?wsdl` where the host is wherever the service is hosted (`localhost` in your images, or `192.168.1.15` in your question).

The endpoint to where to send the SOAP request should be `<the_host>/webservice/WebServiceFOX.asmx`.

ASP.NET generates those pages you see to allow you to test the service inside the browser with GET requests. In those pages there should be a link to the WSDL (in English it's a link called the "Service Description").